# How to remove "Note:" coming before the command result?

Tags: linux, shell, tomcat, networking, grep

I am trying to get the tomcat service running in my linux system through below command

> chkconfig --list | grep -i on | sed -n '/tomcat/p'| awk '{print $1}'

and the output I am getting is

```
Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
      systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
      systemd configuration.

      If you want to list systemd services use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
      To see services enabled on particular target use
      'systemctl list-dependencies [target]'.

tomcat9
```

I just want to get the service name which is "tomcat9". What change I need to do in the command ?

Comment: may be those other lines are showing up on `stderr`?

Comment: Yes, stderr. `chkconfig --list 2>/dev/null` to get them out.

Comment: its working.. but what are the consequences of chkconfig --list 2>/dev/null command. `chkconfig --list 2>/dev/null | grep -i on | sed -n '/tomcat/p'| awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 1):

Add this `awk` filter:

```
|awk -v skip=-1 '/^Note:/{skip=7} skip-- >= 0{next} 1'
```

It skips seven lines if the first word in the first line is "Note:".